# iis 7.5 website not reachable in lan

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, iis-7.5

I'm running a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 and want to deploy an old silverlight business application with membership provider and wcf data services (not ria) on it, so everyone in the LAN could run the application out of their browser.

I installed the IIS role with some roleservices (asp.net, authentication etc.) and created a new site where visual studio publishes the needed files.

On this Server runs also a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, which is used by the silverlight application.
The Server doesn't run any domain services.

[EDIT] resolved, Firewall blocked this.
I can reach the the application only on the server (localhost:port, or ip:port, hostname:port) but not from any other machine. 
[/EDIT]

Maybe someone has an idea?

Regards

Comment: Have you enabled TCP/IP Protocol for the service: Sql Server Configuration Manager -> Sql Server Network Configuration -> Protocols -> Enable TCP/IP -> Restart?

Comment: No, but nothing changed after enabling TCP/IP and restarting the SQL Server Service. Still getting a message "user could not be retrieved".

Comment: Did you also setup the membership provider's database/tables? Otherwise the forms authentication will not find the user (I am assuming the previous business app used a standard ASP.net membership provider database).

Comment: It's an older project so I've copied the membership providers table/procedures/views to the local running SQL Server. It only works with ip:port or localhost:port but not with hostname:port.

Comment: What error are you getting in the IIS logs? [Where is my IIS log file](http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a154/where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx)

Comment: @Amicable I'm waiting for downloading the free editionof SmarterStats.

Comment: @Amicable how to I convert my IIS log with smarterstats?

Comment: I have not used SmarterStats, I was linking that as it describes where IIS logs can be found. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a firewall running on the server it is likely that this is blocking access to the port you are running your Application on
If you don't have a third party firewall installed, maybe Windows Firewall has turned itself on

Comment: Thanks. Really stupid. But the other problem still exists (no login when I visit the website through its hostname)

Comment: Errr that doesn't make a lot of sense that it works with the IP but not the hostname. When you say "no login" do you mean the windows authentication login box doesn't appear or something?

Comment: the forms authentication login appears, but after sending user/pw i get a message "user could not be retrieved". I would debug it, but it doesn't load the symbols :/

Comment: Remote debugging says it needs administrator rights. There fore I created a user with admin rights but it doesn't work.

Comment: But you can login fine on the IP address

Comment: Do you use the same user to access the database through the management studio?

Comment: Login via IP works. Login via Hostname gives me the error i posted in the original post. @t3hn00b yes, the user works via webconfig and via management studio.

Answer (score 0):

> To determine where your IIS log files are stored, please perform the
>   following steps on your server:
>
> Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools Run Internet
>   Information Services (IIS). Find your Web site under the tree on the
>   left. Right-click on it and choose Properties. On the Web site tab,
>   you will see an option near the bottom that says "Active Log Format."
>   Click on the Properties button. At the bottom of the General
>   Properties tab, you will see a box that contains the log file
>   directory and the log file name. The full log path is comprised of the
>   log file directory plus the first part of the log file name. For
>   example, if the dialog box displayed the following values:
>
> Log file directory: C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles Log file name:
>   W3SVC1\exyymmdd.log

```
2012-05-08 23:55:19 W3SVC740447538 192.168.100.134 POST /_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx - 1339 - 192.168.100.134 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.3615) 401 2 2148074254
```

Here's a sample line from my IIS log. It's all timestamped so you can see at 23:55 I was getting some "401 2" accesss denied messages, with the windows error code "2148074254".

You can then use this data to trouble shoot your error message.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has been written to the log file :-/